# SciChart Column Series LabelFormatting

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, scichart

I have a data series `List<Tuple<string,double>>` from which I create a `XyDataSeries<double, double>`. I use the following `LabelFormatter`.

```
public class SciChartCustomLabelFormatter : ILabelFormatter
{
    private readonly string[] _xLabels;
    public SciChartCustomLabelFormatter(string[] xLabels)
    {
        _xLabels = xLabels;
    }
    public void Init(IAxis parentAxis)
    {
    }
    public void OnBeginAxisDraw()
    {
    }
    public ITickLabelViewModel CreateDataContext(IComparable dataValue)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public ITickLabelViewModel UpdateDataContext(ITickLabelViewModel labelDataContext, IComparable dataValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string FormatLabel(IComparable dataValue)
    {
        var index = (double)Convert.ChangeType(dataValue, typeof(double));
        if (index >= 0 && index < _xLabels.Length)
            return _xLabels[(int)index];

        return index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    public string FormatCursorLabel(IComparable dataValue)
    {
        var index = (double)Convert.ChangeType(dataValue, typeof(double));
        if (index >= 0 && index < _xLabels.Length)
            return _xLabels[(int)index];

        return index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

I want to create a FastColumnRenderableSeries

```
<sciChart:FastColumnRenderableSeries
        x:Name="columnSeries" DataPointWidth="1"
        SeriesColor="#A99A8A" Opacity="0.5"
        XAxisId="BottomAxisId"
        YAxisId="LeftAxisId"
        DataSeries="{Binding Series}">
</sciChart:FastColumnRenderableSeries>
```

with the strings being used as labels for the column series.

At present, I can display the series with YAxis clearly displaying the values. **But how do I use the label formatter to display the XAxis strings?** I don't know what should I do with the methods:

```
public ITickLabelViewModel CreateDataContext(IComparable dataValue)
```

and

```
public ITickLabelViewModel UpdateDataContext(ITickLabelViewModel labelDataContext, IComparable dataValue)
```

I'm trying to create a Pareto chart here.

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed in SciChart v3.0 but we have a recently updated article here on '[Overview of the Label Provider API](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17199/30/overview-of-the-labelprovider-api)'

I would suggest inheriting LabelProviderBase as this implements many of the interface methods that you don't need to worry about.

You can specify text labels with [LabelProvider](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17198/30/specifying-text-labels-with-ilabelprovider) as follows:

```
public class CustomLabelProvider : LabelProviderBase
{
    /// <summary>Formats a label for the axis from the specified data-value passed in</summary>
    /// <param name="dataValue">The data-value to format</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted label string</returns>
    public override string FormatLabel(IComparable dataValue)
    {
        return dataValue.ToString(); // TODO: Implement as you wish
    }
    /// <summary>Formats a label for the cursor, from the specified data-value passed in</summary>
    /// <param name="dataValue">The data-value to format</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted cursor label string</returns>
    public override string FormatCursorLabel(IComparable dataValue)
    {
        return dataValue.ToString();// TODO: Implement as you wish
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML

```
<!-- Assumes you have declared the CustomLabelProvider as a static resource -->
<s:NumericAxis LabelProvider="{StaticResource local:CustomLabelProvider}"/>
```

Finally, if you need more information, there is a complete walkthrough on [Screenshots, Printing and String Axis Labels here](http://www.scichart.com/screenshots-xps-printing-x-axis-text-labels/) with downloadable sample (updated to use v3.0 of the API).

[image: String Axis in SciChart WPF Charts]

***Disclosure:*** I am the MD and owner of [SciChart WPF Charts](http://www.scichart.com)